# How do posts from reddit automatically open up in the Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I've been searching for an answer and there isn't a clear one. Reddit has links to Facebook posts and seems like they always open up in the Facebook app. Viewing their source, the link is just a simple link like https://facebook.com/videos/28435523

How does Reddit trigger this? I've been testing links and they always open up as a m.facebook.com link

Comment: Most likely: App Links

Comment: It's on reddit's mobile view. It's a link that goes into the Facebook app, not a link into Reddit.

Comment: _“It's a link that goes into the Facebook app”_ - which app links can be used for … Can’t tell for sure whether that’s the mechanism used, maybe reddit has some JS logic attached to help facilitate this. Try and debug it in your browser dev tools to find out more (like what click event handlers might be attached, etc.)